# Which is better, creating functions for onClick or creating Listeners?

Tags: java, android, performance

I have watched different tutorials on android development from different channels.

One of them makes functions for onClick events and then adds them on the attribute of the View.

Example:

```
public void change(View v){
    ((TextView) findViewbyId(R.id.example)).setText("Changed");
}
```

And then adds this to the attribute of the button.

But the other one implements the View.OnClickListener interface, and it becomes like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView output;
    private EditText edit;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.change: {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Change button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } break;
            case R.id.input:{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Typing..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } break;
            default: break;
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.change);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.nothing)).setOnClickListener(this);
        edit = findViewById(R.id.input);
        edit.setOnClickListener(this);
        output = findViewById(R.id.output);
    }
```

Im new to android development, so I was wondering which is better? Which is more used professionally? and why? Thank you!

Comment: if one was _significantly_ better than the other, why would we have more than one way of doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using XML attribute

```
android:onClick="change"
```

both ways are proper and you may pick more appropriate. If you have one and only clickable `View` then definining XML attr pointing on some method will produce less code, but if you have more of them then it may be easier for manage all of them (e.g. removing/disabling click handling during runtime) by Java code and handle all clicks in one `onClick` method

note you if you have `implements View.OnClickListener` in your `Activity` then you may also write

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

and then you don't have to call `setOnClickListener(this)` in code. oftenly this makes that you don't even have to `findViewById` and reference to `View`